# How to add characters before and after h2 innerhtml

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've scoured for ways to do this, I'm probably just missing something very obvious, and for that I am sorry.

I'm trying to add two characters to a `h2` element. Which I have done, but if I do more than one `h2` the first one is copied. I would like the unique innerHTML of each `h2` to have these characters added before and after.

I am aware I could do this with css but I already have before and after on the element doing other things.

```js
$(window).on("load", function() {
// On page load, add greater than and less than signs to all h2s
var regH2 = $('h2').html();
$('h2').html( '&#60;' + regH2 + '&#62;' );

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>header1</h2>
<h2>header2</h2>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

```
$('h2').each(function(){
  var regH2 = $(this).html();
  $(this).html( '&#60;' + regH2 + '&#62;' );
});
```

Comment: You are beautiful and it worked, thank you so very much.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the [`callBack`](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-function) function of `.html()`,

```
$(window).on("load", function() {
   $('h2').html(function(_,regH2){ 
     return '&#60;' + regH2 + '&#62;'; 
   });
});
```

In the above code, `regH2` will receive the old html string every time.

Answer (score 0):

My answer uses CSS instead of JS:

```css
h2:before { content:'<'; }
h2:after  { content:'>'; }
```

```html
<h2>header1</h2>
<h2>header2</h2>
```

This renders the content with "<" and ">" even before your page has loaded completely.

If :before and :after is already in use, consider adding extra elements like this:

```css
h2 span:before { content:'<'; }
h2 span:after  { content:'>'; }
```

```html
<h2><span>header1</span></h2>
<h2><span>header2</span></h2>
```

For me I alway weep when static content is added via JS. ;)